# Wanted: nonassociative array in AWK

Tags: awk, performance, buffer

I am looking at speeding up some code in AWK by serially processing an
internal string representation instead of serially processing 
an array representation.  (For Examples 1 and 2 below assume datasep is a single character that is not part of the computable data.)  So instead of:

```
# Example 1
split(datastr,data,datasep)
for(i=1; i in data; i++) { 
     # Use data[i]
     }
```

I want to try something like

```
 # Example 2 - buggy code assumes datastr terminated by datasep
 l= length(datastr)
 for(j=1; j < l ; ) {
      datumlen = match(substr(datastr,j+1),datasep)
      #Use substr(datastr,j+1,datumlen-1)
      j+=datumlen
      }
```

This is because I want to save memory and lookup time that
is involved in using an associative array (data), and also because
I have faith in how match and substr are implemented.  I
plan to start with datastr having length > 10^6 bytes (with
datumlen < 5 most of the time), and
push it up from there.  I can stream out the results, so
I am not worried about memory requirements of the code, but
I may need to make more than one pass over datastr, so I would
like to avoid streaming datastr (unless that is even faster).

So the question is:  Are there memory- and access-efficient
routines that improve on Example 1 and look something
like Example 2?  Or would I be better off trusting the
internal buffering AWK and the system use to process input files, and
just make several passes over the same input file?

EDIT 2015.09.18: (I am not registered in this forum yet, so answering
a comment here.)  I am using gawk 4.1.3 on a non-Unix platform.  I am
interested in having a small portable environment in which to do certain
types of computing.  I do not know enough about gawk internals, and 
thought perhaps someone reading this forum had tried something like this
before.  I will end up profiling the different ways if I receive no
other suggestions.  END EDIT 2015.09.18

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Tweaking" Paseman, 2015.09.16

Comment: If you're talking about performance, you need to specify which version of awk you're using. Have you done benchmarks to see if this was really a showstopper? If it is, why aren't you considering other languages that offer a richer set of data structures?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some test code for gawk 4.1.3 I wrote to answer the question.  The original data in PFILE was numeric, and I was trying to compress things by storing differences between consecutive entries in DFILE.

```
BEGIN{ RLS=bufstr=""; SEP =":" ; PFILE="somenumbers.txt" ; DFILE= "diffile.txt"
if (ATEST=="") ATEST=1
accumulate=lastdatum=0 ; BIGN=5500000 ; DATALENMAX=7 ;TUNELEN=2048
for(i=1; i < BIGN ; i++) {
     getline nextdatum < PFILE
     d = nextdatum -lastdatum
#     RLS = RLS d SEP
     ibuf( d SEP )
     print d > DFILE
     lastdatum=nextdatum  }
# RLS = RLS "0"
ibuf("0")
if (length(bufstr) > 0) { RLS = RLS bufstr ; bufstr="" }
print (RLSlen=length(RLS))
close(PFILE) ; close(DFILE)
timestmp["start"] = systime()
if (ATEST==1){
  split(RLS,data,SEP)
  timestmp["endsplit"] = systime()
  for(i=1; i in data; i++){     accumulate += 1*data[i]     }
  }
if (ATEST==2){
  for(j=1; j<RLSlen ; j+=datalen) {
     datalen=match(substr(RLS,j, DATALENMAX),SEP)
     accumulate  += 1*substr(RLS,j,datalen-1)     }
  }
if (ATEST==3) {
  while((getline diff < DFILE)>0){  accumulate  += 1*diff }
  close(DFILE)
  }
print accumulate 
timestmp["end"] = systime()
for(t in timestmp) print t, (1*timestmp[t] - 1*timestmp["start"])
}

function ibuf(str) {   bufstr=bufstr str
   if (length(bufstr) > TUNELEN) { RLS = RLS bufstr ; bufstr="" }
}
```

The ibuf() function and TUNELEN parameter aren't crucial, I just got tired of seeing the allocated memory value thrash back and forth because of the assignment

RLS = RLS d SEP

so I decided to buffer that part.

I expected the second and third sections (ATEST=2 and 3) to perform a little faster than the first section.  That did not happen.  Working with the arrays always seemed a little faster, in the extreme about twice as fast as section 2, and a little faster than section 3.  However, the array version used about
10 times (or more) memory because of having to store indices as well as values.

I initially tested section 2 without a DATAMAXLEN value, and that made things very slow because of the repeated substr() call.  The section 2 method
definitely does not give more speed, although it does save on memory used by
the input data.

In all, if you have memory to burn, use associative arrays.  If you have a good disk, read from a file.  If you have to conserve, creep through the string, but be careful just to look at small pieces.  On my system, I may run into memory limits, so I will probably read from a file for my application.  If anyone sees a way to tweak section 2, say by using index or some other memory-conserving means to access the string, I would like to know of it.

Gerhard "My Mileage Varies Pretty Often" Paseman, 2015.09.30

Comment: Although it is fine to answer your own question post, it is not ok to use chit-chat on this Q&A site, as you would have known had you read the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). Having your name under a post twice is really not necessary and degrades an otherwise possible good post. Additionally it is not place in answer to ask additional questions.